# Using the result of a concat filter in a complex filter in FFmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to use the result of a -concat filter as an inuput of another filter, for example I'd like to scale and pad the result of the concat but can't find anything. It needs to be done in a single command so I can't just take the output file as an input.

an example of what I need would be so but it doesn't work

```
    ffmpeg -i irregular.mp4 -i intro.mp4 -i outro.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=1080:610:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase[scaled];[scaled]crop=1080:610[cropped];[cropped]setdar=16/9[a];[2]scale=1080:610:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase[scaledIntro];[scaledIntro]crop=1080:610[b];[b]setdar=16/9[b];[3]scale=1080:610:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase[scaledOutro];[scaledOutro]crop=1080:610[c];[c]setdar=16/9[c];[b:v:0][b:a:0][a:v:0][a:a:0][c:v:0][c:a:0]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[concatenated][concatenateda];[concatenated]pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2+(0):(oh-ih)/2-(0) [padded];[padded][1]overlay=0:0[framed]" -map "[framed]" -map"[concatenateda]" output.mp4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"it doesn't work" doesn't helpfully describe the problem, but try:

```
ffmpeg -i intro.mp4 -i irregular.mp4 -i outro.mp4 -filter_complex "[0]scale=1080:610:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:610,setdar=16/9[intro];[1]scale=1080:610:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:610,setdar=16/9[main];[2]scale=1080:610:force_original_aspect_ratio=increase,crop=1080:610,setdar=16/9[outro];[intro][0:a][main][1:a][outro][2:a]concat=n=3:v=1:a=1[viddyo][audio];[viddyo]pad=1080:1920:(ow-iw)/2+(0):(oh-ih)/2-(0)[padded];[padded][0]overlay=0:0[video]" -map "[video]" -map "[audio]" output.mp4
```

See the [FFmpeg filtering introduction](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtering-Introduction) for a detailed explanation of the syntax.

Comment: Thank you, my problem was the syntax, I couldn't figure it out, I didn't "chain" the filters with "," because I am using java to encapsulate the commands and haven't added chaining yet, are there cases where it is necessary or can it always be done without? the syntax does work now. Also is there a way I can use the audio of an output stream of another filter like I did before or can I only take the audio directly from an input like you did?

Thanks a lot man btw you really saved me a lot of time.

Comment: @TheodoreTs'ai You do not need to chain the filters if you do not want to: `filter1,filter2,filter3` can be changed to something like `filter1[f1];[f1]filter2[f2];[f2]filter3` if you prefer. Yes, you can take the audio from a filter just like you can with video.